# Search for string in dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to create a new column whose value is based on whether an existing column contains a defined string:

E.g.

```
df =  pd.DataFrame([['USDCAD exotic option',-100],['USDSGD vanilla option',-20]])
```

I would like to create a third column that simply states Vanilla or Exotic, based on the string in the first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex pattern matching to extract from your first column:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([['USDCAD exotic option',-100],['USDSGD vanilla option',-20]])

df["what"] = df[0].str.extract(r"USD.* (.*) option")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                       0    1     what
0   USDCAD exotic option -100   exotic
1  USDSGD vanilla option  -20  vanilla
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick - I'm specifically looking to classify into those two (vanilla or exotic). So the text will contain one of those words but the rest of the text format will vary - so is there a way of creating what you have above by using isin, for example?

Comment: @Ben  `df["what"] = df[0].str.extract(r"(exotic|vanilla)")`